# Finding the principal value of $\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^{-3}\right)^{1-i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> I am trying to find the principal value of, $$\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^{-3}\right)^{1-i}.$$

My attempt:

I use the fact that $PVz^a=\exp(a\text{Log}(z))$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$\ $0$ and $a\in\mathbb{C}$.
So, \begin{align}
PV\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^{-3}\right)^{1-i}&=\exp\left((3i-3)\text{Log}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)\right) \\
&=\exp\left((3i-3)\left(\ln\left|\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right|+i\text{Arg}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)\right)\right) \\
&=\exp\left((3i-3)\left(i\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right) \\
&=-\exp(-\pi)
\end{align}
Is this correct? I am unsure if my first step (to determine $a$) is valid.

**edit**

following through the same steps, but using $z=-1$ and $a=1-i$, I get the answer $-\exp(\pi)$. Why does,
$$PV\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^{-3}\right)^{1-i}\neq PV\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^{3i-3}??$$

Comment: $\frac{1+\sqrt 3i}{2}$ is cubic root of $x^3+1=0$ which has a solution $x=-1 =\cos \pi=e^{\pi i}$.

Comment: I have put an edit in. I hope this helps explain my question

Comment: The standard laws of exponents don't apply to principle values.

Answer (score 1):

i'm denoting cube roots of unity i.e, $(1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$by  $ 1 \ or \ \omega^3,\omega, \omega^2 $

therefore,

$ 1+x+x^2 $ has roots $\omega , \omega^2$

$\implies$ $1-x+x^2$ has roots $-\omega,\omega^2$ and product of it's roots i.e, $-\omega^3 =1\implies \omega^{-3}=-1 $

therefore your equation can be written as

$\left[(-\omega)^{-3}\right]^{1-i}=\left[-(\omega)^{-3}\right]^{1-i}=\left[-1 \times -1 \right]^{1-i}=(1)^{1-i}=e^{2n \pi \ i(1-i)}=e^{2n\pi (1+i)}=e^{2n\pi}$  it is purely real with principle argument zero and magnitude $e^{2n\pi}$

where ,

$n=0,1,2.......$